# How to click on the Javascript button in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

In the web page there are some rows with same button name. Xpath is not working for me since xpath id name is same for all rows.xpath id is //*[@id="btnChangeStatusThisOrder"]

This is the code for one row. I have to click on this specific button from this code. How can I write code for this Javascript button. Also ID `btnChangeStatusThisOrder` is available for many rows.

```
<a href="javascript: handleOrderStatusChange('251')" id="btnChangeStatusThisOrder" class="actionBtn">Go</a>
```

Comment: xpath: //a[@id='btnChangeStatusThisOrder']

Comment: Is this button always in the same place?

Comment: what do you mean `Xpath is not working for me.`? could you show what have you tried?. also provide at-least 10 lines of html around this target element if `id` is not unique.

Comment: @maneeshpn Update the question with your code trials and the error (if any)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for this specific button your XPath should be something like this:

```
GoButtonXpath = "//a[@id='btnChangeStatusThisOrder' and text()='Go']"
```

If you are looking to click a few of the buttons you can get them with `findElements`, not `findElement`.

Hope this helpes you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code for javascript button.

```
JavascriptExecutor JS=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;

        JS.executeScript("document.getEementByXpath('//a[@id='btnChangeStatusThisOrder']).click()'", button);
```

hope this help!!

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("xpath of the button"));

JavascriptExecutor JS=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);